Baseline profile generator retains app state between launches
I've created a baseline profile generator module by following the official documentation steps.
I noticed that when I launch profile generation it doesn't re-install the app, if it is already installed. Instead it launches the already installed one, which might be in a state, which I don't want to cover with profile.
Is it OK? How can I prevent this?
